# Showing that property (1),(2)

Tags: functional-analysis

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me with the following problem.

> Show that (1), (2)

if $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ : $f''(x)+f(x)=0, f(0)=1, f'(0)=0$

then

(1). $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ : $\{f(x)\}^2+\{f'(x)\}^2=1$

(2). $x>0$ : $1-\frac{1}{2}x^2\leq f(x) \leq 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4$

Answer (score 2):

For (1), differentiate it to show that $f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ be constant and then find the constant by substituting in appropriate values.

For (2), consider the first few terms of the Taylor expansion.

[Solving the differential equation might help you out a bit if you want some intuition.]

Answer (score 1):

For (1), just multiply $f''(x)+f(x)=0$ by $f'(x)$, and integrate.